# Webforms HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always true

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-membership

**EDIT:** Can anyone explain why I am getting "/" for the username? See my "Answer" below

I created a new WebForms application in VS2013 (.NET 4.51) which included the "new" Identity membership provider. I wanted to use the older Membership provider so did as follows.

1. Populated the necessary entries in web.config as follows:

:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
   <providers><add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
 </membership>
```

and

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I doubled checked the authentication node:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Account/Login" timeout="120" defaultUrl="/">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

My login code is as follows:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
{
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("/", chkRememberMe.Checked); 
}
```

and my logout code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

however HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated **always** returns TRUE, which means that even after I logout I can access any page in the site even through I have the following restriction:

```
  <!-- Entire site is secured -->
  <location path=".">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

What am I missing here? I am guessing there is still some legacy from the original Identity provider which I have not eradicated which is causing this issue. At this point security is not working at all for me and I need to get it working without using the new Identity membership provider which is the default for new applications generated via the new application template in VS2013.

All pointers and suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: To confirm: the user does get prompted to login when they first use the application prior to being able to access any form in the application, correct?

Comment: @JimMSDN no user never gets prompted at all. Even after I clear all the cookies from the browser. So clearly for some reason the security susbsystem is not being invoked. I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I came back to this today and now pages are authenticating as expected (WT....). So I am guessing that there must have been a cookie somewhere that was not being cleared. However something is still not right.

Once the user has authenticated when I inspect:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

I am getting:

```
"/"
```

as the result instead of the name the user entered when they logged in via:

```
Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)
```

ie. why am I not getting the value of **txtUserName.Text** instead of **/**

I guess a related question is, is there a HOWTO on how to revert a project from Identity to the previous Membership system?