# Reverted to Membership from Identity and getting strange result for logged in user name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Using VS2013 Update 1 I created a new WebForms project. This project uses the "new" Identity membership provider. I did not want to use that so I reverted back to the Membership provider (For more detail see [Webforms HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911930/webforms-httpcontext-current-user-identity-isauthenticated-always-true))

I must still have something still wrong as once the user has authenticated when I inspect:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

I am getting:

```
"/"
```

[image]

as the result instead of the name the user entered when they logged in via:

Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)
ie. why am I not getting the value of txtUserName.Text instead of /

I have verified that the SQL being exectuted when

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

is being accessed is returning the expected values via the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Limit1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Limit1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Limit1].[PasswordQuestion] AS [PasswordQuestion], 
    [Limit1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
    [Limit1].[IsApproved] AS [IsApproved], 
    [Limit1].[IsLockedOut] AS [IsLockedOut], 
    [Limit1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
    [Limit1].[LastLoginDate] AS [LastLoginDate], 
    [Limit1].[LastActivityDate] AS [LastActivityDate], 
    [Limit1].[LastPasswordChangedDate] AS [LastPasswordChangedDate], 
    [Limit1].[LastLockoutDate] AS [LastLockoutDate]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        [Extent1].[LastActivityDate] AS [LastActivityDate], 
        [Extent3].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent3].[PasswordQuestion] AS [PasswordQuestion], 
        [Extent3].[IsApproved] AS [IsApproved], 
        [Extent3].[IsLockedOut] AS [IsLockedOut], 
        [Extent3].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
        [Extent3].[LastLoginDate] AS [LastLoginDate], 
        [Extent3].[LastPasswordChangedDate] AS [LastPasswordChangedDate], 
        [Extent3].[LastLockoutDate] AS [LastLockoutDate], 
        [Extent3].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM   [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Applications] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ApplicationId] = [Extent2].[ApplicationId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Memberships] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent3].[UserId]
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

here is my web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="MyApp2" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="MyApp2" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="MyApp2" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

so the issue **"must be"** that I have the Identity membership provider referenced in some way somewhere. Can anyone help me out here as I am really stuck.

I guess a related question is, is there a HOWTO on how to revert a project from Identity to the previous Membership system?

**EDIT**

After thinking it was all working after changing the applicationName to "MyApp" when I went back to play with the app again I am back to the old "bad" behavior where I get "/" for the user name. So I changed the database to MyApp2 as well as the web.config and still no difference.

I now also include a screenshot of the tables from the database in case this helps with anything. I really need to figure this out so would appreciate any insights. Am also happy to provide other diagnostics as needed.
[image]

Comment: Have you got the `web.config` changes done correctly for the membership, profile and role providers?

Comment: @DavidG I have added my web.config settings for you to have a look at.

Comment: Are you running any custom implementations at all? Noticed that your `applicationName` value is "/". Could you try changing this value to see if it appears as the user name.

Comment: Membership.ValidateUser just returns boolean. What kind of authentication do you use? I'd suggest debug the process of logging in, which would look like `if(membership.Validate()) then SetAuthenticationCookie` - and there would be someone who stores incorrect name into the cookie. By the way, *query looks like ORM-generated*, while Default membership provider uses hardcoded one. And `where` clause is missing...

Comment: I think it's possible your issue lies in the `applicationname` field in all three of the web.config excerpts, as that form of Membership (by default) ties itself to an entry in an Application table in the database.  I'd try inserting a usable name in the `applicationname` field instead of "/".

Comment: @post_erasmus that made it work! However I don't understand why. I have had a look into some other projects created before Indentity was the default and they have a "/" as the application name and work just fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TheEdge I'm curious what version of Membership they're using.  Version 2.0 was released as a Nuget package for Universal Membership (all .NET applications, not just ASP.NET). If what you're saying is true, I suspect they're using an earlier version that wasn't "Universal" and that achieving universality meant that .NET could no longer safely infer the application name.  If you want any of this in a formal answer with what links I can find, let me know.

Comment: @post_erasmus and others. Changing the applicaiton name did not seem to actually fix things. See my EDIT from the original post. So I am back to the original problem that the username being returned when I login with the user is a "/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is always the simple solution isn't it?

As it turns out I had not placed my ASPX code for my login page within an aspx:login. This meant that the cookie was not getting set correctly as all I was doing was Membership.RedirectFromLogin().

So once I put things into an aspx:login all was well. Hope this helps someone else in the future.